# Denjoy example in the Poincaré–Bendixson theorem

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, smooth-manifolds

I have already finished understanding the Poincaré-Bendixson theorem as a consequence of Schwartz's theorem, but I also want to analyze the [example that Denjoy](https://mathoverflow.net/a/245042/171387) gave in $C^1$ that is not within the case taken in Schwartz's theorem. Does anyone know where I can find that detailed example? or maybe some generalization of this example? I would like to review it in detail to finish closing the idea of why Schwartz's theorem cannot be valid for flows of class $C^1$.

**Schwartz Theorem.-** Let $M$ be a compact, connected, two-dimensional manifold of class $C^2$. Let $\alpha: \mathbb R \times M \to M$ be a $C^2$ flow on $M$. Let $\Omega \subset M$ be an $\alpha$-minimal set. Then $\Omega$ must be one of the following:
$a)$ a singleton consisting of a fixed point
$b)$ a single, closed orbit homeomorphic to $S^1$
$c)$ all of $M$ which is homeomorphic to a torus $T^2$

Comment: Suggestion: State explicitly the content of the Schwartz theorem you refer to. You might also specify which person named Schwartz proved it.

Comment: Done I edited it.

Comment: See p. 37 of these excellent notes, for a careful description of the Denjoy counterexamples: https://www.math.ens.psl.eu/~sghazoua/cdln.pdf

Comment: There are good notes on the Denjoy counterexample by John Milnor, here: http://www.math.stonybrook.edu/~jack/DYNOTES/dn15.pdf.